# Unable to Center My footer in html

Tags: css, html, footer

I am currently using this css sheet to stylize my page but no matter what I do I cannot get the footer to line up with the main content of my webpage. It seems to be an centering issue. 
Here is my css:

```
    .footnav
        {

            padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px; 

            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
            color:white;

            position:relative;
            z-index:100;
        }

        .footnav    li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        display: inline;
        font-weight:bold;

        }

        .footnav li {
        list-style-type: none;


        }
```

Here is the code that previous css it is stylizing, I apologize if it is a lot to read.

```
<div class="footnav" >
    <ul class="nav1">
        <li class="header">Main</li>
        <li><Home</li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="nav2">
        <li class="header">Aventure</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>Map</li>
    </ul >
    <ul class="nav3">
        <li class="header">Survival</li>
        <li>Guide</li>
        <li>Gear</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the css for the content area, that I am trying to line my footer with.

```
.content
        {
            color:white;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:none;
            font-family:sans-serif;
            padding:30px;

            margin:auto;
            margin-top:10px;

            width:70%;
            position:relative;
            z-index:14;

            opacity:1;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:10px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:5px;
            background-color:#000000;
            border-color:#FFFFFF;
            border-right-color:#999999;
            border-left-color:#666666;
            border-bottom-color:#333333;
        }
```

I know that it involves trying to take half the width of the body of the webpage, but for my page I used percentages instead of pixels. I am not sure how to handle that. Thanks in advance and once  again, I apologize for the lengthy question but the only way to properly assist me, would be to have the full picture. If there is any more material needed just ask.

Comment: This work in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dhs43gmj/4/

Answer (score 0):

try to add `display: inline-block;` to `.footnav ul`. The `ul` blocks would otherwise have 100% width - this way they can be next to each other, and be centerded together. `inline-block` limits the width, therefore you also should add a `width` setting to this rule. So it is:

```
.footnav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

(The actual width depends on the content of your `li` elements in those nav lists)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the footer content in `<center>` tags `</center>`. They automatically align any child content with the center of the page.

Comment: are those tags okay to use in html5

Comment: @OneStepBeyond I've used them before in all sorts of environments, including HTML5

Comment: according this website it is not supported in html5 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp